# Flow property is missing in mixed passed

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm using a `BroadcastChannel` to pass data from one browser window to another. However, using Flow I get the following error: *Flow: property `type` is missing in mixed [1].*

This is my code:

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('background');
channel.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  if (data.type === 'OK') {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false, success: true, error: false });
  }
  else if (data.type === 'ERROR') {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false, success: false, error: true });
  }
};
```

I also tried to define my own type as such:

```
type MessageType = {
  type: String,
  payload: String,
};

...

channel.onmessage = ({ data }: { data: MessageType }) => {
  if (data.type === 'OK') {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }

  if (data.type === 'ERROR') {
    alert('ERROR!');

    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }
};
```

But then Flow gives me the following error: *Flow: Cannot assign function to `channel.onmessage` because `MessageType` [1] is incompatible with mixed [2] in property `data` of the first argument.*

I figured out that the argument, passed by the message handler is declared like this:

```
declare class MessageEvent extends Event {
  data: mixed;
  origin: string;
  lastEventId: string;
  source: WindowProxy;
}
```

So, if data is declared to be of type mixed but I need it to be a custom type, how would I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values of type `mixed` can be absolutely anything, including `undefined`, `null` or objects without a `prototype`.

You need to explicitly check that the actual type of `data` has a `type` field before being able to access it:

```
channel.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  // 1. Make sure it's not null
  // 2. Make sure it's an object. This is only so that we can...
  // 3. ...call hasOwnProperty to make sure it has a 'type' field
  if(data != null && typeof data === 'object' && data.hasOwnProperty('type')) {
    // Inside this condition, Flow knows that the 'type' field exists
    if (data.type === 'OK') {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false, success: true, error: false });
    }
    else if (data.type === 'ERROR') {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false, success: false, error: true });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Is there some sort of shortcut for this?

Comment: This can be simplified as `if (data && data.type) {data.type === 'OK' ? this.setState(some_state) : this.setState(other_state);}`